# Manipular itens de uma Action Bar fora do escopo de onCreateOptionsMenu()

Tags: java, android, actionbar

Possuo em minha Action Bar um item para exibir o progresso (um ProgressBar) caso uma requisição esteja ocorrendo. Quando a requisição ocorre, devo mostrar o ProgressBar e ocultar os outros itens, quando a requisição termina, devo ocultar o ProgressBar e mostrar os outros itens.

### Diculdade

A requisição, ou seja, minha AsyncTask, é executada ao iniciar a minha Activity (na verdade, é um Fragment), ou seja, antes de o sistema operacional chamar a criação do menu com `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

Preciso recuperar e manipular os itens de uma [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) fora do escopo do método `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, ou seja no início e ao final da AsyncTask.

#### Observação

A AsyncTask está decladarada em uma classe a parte. A activity delega para uma classe que manipula e gerencia os métodos desta AsyncTask.

**Como manipular uma ActionBar fora do escopo de `onCreateOptionsMenu()`?**

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que pretende fazer com o menu após obtido. Obrigado.

Comment: Eduardo, preciso ocultar/exibir. Vou detalhar melhor na pergunta.

Comment: Em qual momento você pretende fazer isto, que não pode usar o evento onCreateOptionsMenu().

Comment: Após a execução de uma asynctask. O item que quero ocultar é um progressbar. Mostrá-lo durante a requisição e ocultá-lo e exibir outros itens quando terminada a requisição.

Comment: Você pode pegar o `Menu` no evento `onCreateOptionsMenu()` e passar por parâmetro para sua `AsyncTask`. O que acha da ideia ?

Comment: Minha asynctask é executada no onStart(), portanto antes do onCreateOptionsMenu() acontecer.

Comment: Não pode mudar o método em que a sua `AsyncTask` é executada ?

Comment: A sua *AsyncTask* é declarada na Activity onde é usada (nested classe) ou é uma classe à parte?

Comment: Em uma classe à parte, @ramaral. A activity delega para uma outra classe que contém a AsyncTask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível manipular algo antes de ter sido criado.
Portanto só terá acesso ao *Menu* depois do método `onCreateOptionsMenu()` ter sido executado.

Sugiro que faça o seguinte:

- Declare uma variável privada para guardar a referência ao *Menu*: `mMenu`.
- Declare um método para executar a *AsyncTask*.
- No método `onCreateOptionsMenu()` verifique se `mMenu` é nulo, se for guarde nela a referência ao menu e chame o método que executa a *AsyncTask*.
- No método `onStart()` verifique se `mMenu` é nulo, se **não** for chame o método que executa a *AsyncTask*

Assim, quando a *Activity* é criada, a *AsyncTask* é lançada no método `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, nas outras situações, decorrentes do normal ciclo de vida da *Activity*, a *AsyncTask* é lançada no método `onStart()`.

Terá de passar a referência ao *Menu* à sua *AsyncTask*.

Answer (score 2):

Você não pode manipular seu `Menu` antes mesmo dele ser criado.

A forma que acredito ser mais correta é você executar sua `AsyncTask`apos o método `onCreateOptionsMenu()` ser executado, e passar o `Menu` para sua `AsyncTask` por parâmetro.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o método 
 `invalideOptionsMenu()`

Que forçará a chamada do método `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: Caique, como faria para usar a sua abordagem? Pode fornecer um exemplo?